# Is it always true, that if $G$ is a group and $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $|G:A|<\infty\Rightarrow|G:A^x|<\infty$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Is it always true, that if $G$ is a group and $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ then
$$|G:A|<\infty\Rightarrow|G:A^x|<\infty$$
where $x\in G$.

I did as follows: let $|G:A|=n\Rightarrow G=g_1A\sqcup\cdots\sqcup g_nA$ then
$$G=G^x=(g_1A)^x\sqcup\cdots\sqcup(g_nA)^x=$$
$$=g_1^xA^x\cup\cdots\cup g_n^xA^x$$
$\Rightarrow |G:A^x|\le|G:A|\lt \infty$.

But I'm not sure if I solved the problem correctly. Please, help me.

Comment: Yes, $|G:A| = |G^x:A^x|$.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*